# What needs to be implemented for the following

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement the following in a method in one of my classes in VB but am getting build errors:

```
Public Sub sendMessage()
    Dim sUrl As String
    Dim sAPI_ID, sPassword, sUsername, sMobileNo, sText As String
    Dim oXMLHTTP, sPostData, sResult
    sUrl = "http://api.clickatell.com/http/sendmsg"
    sAPI_ID = "xxxx"
    sPassword = "xxxx"
    sUsername = "xxxx"
    sMobileNo = "xxxx"
    sText = "This is an example message"
    sPostData = "api_id=" & sAPI_ID
    sPostData = sPostData & "&user=" & sUsername
    sPostData = sPostData & "&password=" & sPassword
    sPostData = sPostData & "&to=" & sMobileNo
    sPostData = sPostData & "&text=" & sText
    oXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    oXMLHTTP.Open("POST", sUrl, False)
    oXMLHTTP.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    oXMLHTTP.Send(sPostData)
    sResult = oXMLHTTP.responseText
    oXMLHTTP = Nothing
    Response.Write(sResult)
End Sub
```

The following two lines are underlined and I believe that imports are missing:

```
oXMLHTTP = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
```

And

```
Response.Write(sResult)
```

Would anyone be able to tell me what I need to import or whats missing?

Comment: Get both:'Server' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level. & 'Response' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are built in COM objects in the old ASP:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524716(v=vs.90).aspx

As you can see on that MSDN page, in ASP.NET, there are new classes in the `System.Web` namespace that provide equivalent functionality.  More information about the new classes in .NET can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6w6xys5(v=VS.71).aspx